# Try to make Main Menu in my Wordpress project

Tags: php, wordpress, web, wordpress-theming

How we can make the drop down main Nav in WordPress by using Wp_nav Function?
This is my Code. I try every thing by WP_NAV but i can make this?

```
<nav>
    <h1 class="open"><a class='current' href="index.html">G</a></h1>
     <ul class="no-bullet">
       <li class="current parent"><a class='current' href="index.html">Portfolio</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a href="item.html">Portfolio Item</a></li>
              <li><a href="item.html">Portfolio Item</a></li>
              <li><a href="item.html">Portfolio Item</a></li>
              <li><a href="item.html">Portfolio Item</a></li>
            </ul>
       </li>
       <li class="parent"><a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
           <li><a href="single-post.html">Single Post</a></li>
           <li><a href="author.html">Author Page</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
         <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: That's better, but you're asking about PHP and you haven't attempted to solve the problem with PHP. You should research that and come back when you have a *specific* question about your PHP.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually accomplished via CSS, and not WordPress itself. WordPress will just output the menu as list items and the CSS will provide dropdown portion of it.

There are several step-by-step tutorials on how to do this.

Comment: Thanks for Answering. Plz Check it now and explain how can i do this :)